# Repository does not initialize entity data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository, repository-pattern

I would like to create a Details view with entity framework data using a repository pattern.

This is my interface repository:

```
public interface InterfaceRepositroy: IDisposable
{
    IEnumerable<SubjectContent> GetAll();
    SubjectContent Get(string id);
}
```

This is the toher repository:

```
public class SubjectRepository : InterfaceRepositroy,IDisposable
{
    private irfwebpage20161013070934_dbEntities2 db;

    public IEnumerable<SubjectContent> GetAll()
    {
        return db.Set<SubjectContent>().ToList();
    }
    public SubjectContent Get(string id)
    {
        return db.Set<SubjectContent>().Find(id);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
private InterfaceRepositroy subjectreposi;

public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
    SubjectContent subject = subjectreposi.Get(id);
    return View(subject);
}
```

My View is a standard details template.

It gets an error at this point in the controller:

```
SubjectContent subject = subjectreposi.Get(id);
```

I would really appreciate the help. This is like the fourth version of a repository pattern i am trying to implement but none of them worked so far. I have tried it without interface, with the instance of the subjecrepository or with different linq to sql in the repository. It either gets http error or it doesnt show the data just the names of the data.

Comment: You need to initialise your data context, this is usually done in the constructor

Comment: I would stay away from repository pattern.

Comment: What would you recommend because it still doesn't work? Im just want more than one table of entity data in details view

Answer (score 1):

Create constructors that initialise your data context:

```
public SubjectRepository()
{
     db = new irfwebpage20161013070934_dbEntities2();
}

public SubjectRepository(irfwebpage20161013070934_dbEntities2 dbContext)
{
     db = dbContext;
}
```

This allows you to either initialise your repository with no parameters which will initialise you data context or specify your own data context.

You can now use this like this:

```
var repo = new SubjectRepository();
SubjectContent subject = repo.Get(id);
```